# My servlet is not being called, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am new to Java, and especially new to using sevlets. I am making a VERY simple servlet, but whenever I submit the form the servlet is not being called and I am getting an error. Can someone help me please?

Here is my servlet code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class sampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>"); 
    }
}


<form action="/sampleServlet/" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form "/>
</form>
```

The error that I am getting is: "The requested resource is not available."

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Projekt</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: check your mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to register your servlet in web.xml or use annotation. An example of using annotation is shown below:

```
@WebServlet("/processForm")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("Hello");
    }
}
```

To see how to register in web.xml check this:
[Creating and Configuring Servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html)

To see more examples of annotation use:
[WebServlet annotation examples](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/webservlet-annotation-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your servlet in web.xml, something like that:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>package.sampleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sampleServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Did you provide correct path to your servlet class in `<servlet-class>` ?